# error C2679: binary '>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

For whatever reason while i am trying to compare two int values in a specific functor, it just gives me this error

MVCE

First goes the piece where i call functor

Second is the body of class

Third is the bofy of the functor

```
int main()
{
    int compare;
    std::vector<int> vectInt({ 1, 2, 11, 12, 34 });
    std::cout << "Enter value for comparing: ";
    std::cin >> compare;
    int count = countGreater<int>()(vectInt, compare);
    return 0;
}

class SquareTriangle
{
    int cathetus1, cathetus2;
public:
    SquareTriangle() {}
    ~SquareTriangle() {}
    SquareTriangle(int first, int second)
    {
        this->cathetus1 = first;
        this->cathetus2 = second;
    }
    double getArea() const
    {
        return (cathetus1 * cathetus2) / 2;
    }
    friend bool operator < (const SquareTriangle &first, const SquareTriangle &second)
    {
        if (first.getArea() < second.getArea())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    friend bool operator > (const SquareTriangle &first, const SquareTriangle &second)
    {
        if (first.getArea() > second.getArea())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    friend double operator << (const SquareTriangle &first, const SquareTriangle &second)
    {
        return first.getArea();
    }
    friend double operator += (const SquareTriangle &first, const SquareTriangle &second)
    {
        first.getArea() += second.getArea();
        return first.getArea();
    }
};
typedef SquareTriangle ST;

template <typename Q>
class countGreater
{
    int count = 0;
public:
    int operator () (const std::vector<Q> &ptr, int compare = 0)
    {
        if (sizeof(Q) == sizeof(ST))
        {
            int first, second;
            std::cout << "Enter first cathetus: ";
            std::cin >> first;
            std::cout << "Enter second cathetus: ";
            std::cin >> second;
            ST valueST(first, second);
            for (int i = 0; i < ptr.size(); i++)
            {
                if (ptr[i] > valueST)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ptr.size(); i++)
            {
                *if (ptr[i] > compare)*
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }   
        std::cout << "Number of elements greater than chosen: ";
        return count;
    }
};
```

Line that gives error

```
if (ptr[i] > compare)
```

Full error message
*C2679: binary '>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)*

Comment: And how do you call this functor? What do you use for `Q`?  please provide a [mcve]

Comment: 1. Don't post relevant code as comment, [edit] it into the question. 2. That is still not a [mcve], it's missing important information such as the definition of `ST` and the full error message

Comment: You still have three separate code blocks, not an MVCE. Make one code snippet that you believe should compile on its own.

Comment: @ildjarn If i didn't do anything wrong yet again here it is.
I did not include all the libraries i use as i think they didn't play any role, but i could edit them in if needed

Comment: After fixing up your code to an actual MCVE (https://godbolt.org/z/g56o1W) I get an error on `if (ptr[i] > valueST)` and not on `if (ptr[i] > compare)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I reorder and fix the `#includes`, there are at least two mistakes in your code. first, this does not compile:

```
friend double operator += (const SquareTriangle &first, const SquareTriangle &second)
{
    first.getArea() += second.getArea();
    return first.getArea();
}
```

Because you are trying to assign something to an expression. If you want to increase `first`'s area, you will have to modify the data members (the catheti). Not sure why you are doing it, because it does not make much sense anyway.

---

Second, this `if` line does not compile:

```
if (ptr[i] > valueST)
{
    count++;
}
```

Because `ptr[i]` ends up being an integer, and `valueST` is an instance of your class. Since you don't have a way to compare an `int` with a `SquareTriangle`, it breaks. Not sure what you are trying to do, though. Comparing with the area, maybe?

Comment: @UnholySheep Regarding first mistake, you can ignore it as i was working with some other fragments of the code and it does not realy have any role in MCVE, as for the second i understood what you are trying to say and is there any way i can tell the program to ignore the first if `if (ptr[i] > valueST)` in case i am working with standart integer and not my ST class?

Comment: There are ways to compile different code depending on compile-time conditions, but first you really need to understand what you are trying to do, which is not clear. If I were you, I would create a new question trying to be clear on what you want to achieve. Hope that helps!